# Ansible: I need to use a variable that is in a loop, and use each variable independently

Tags: centos, ansible, centos7

some assistance required if possible...

I have created users from a variable file:

```
"Users": 
 - user1
 - user2
 - user3
```

I need to move files to the home directory of each user. I don't wish to do it like this, as it would mean writing an individual line for each user:

```
- name: Copy Playbooks
  copy:
    src: /etc/ansible/playbooks/file.yml
    dest: /home/user1/playbooks
```

Doing it like the below would mean ansible is trying to add to the home directory of {{ "user1" "user2" "user3" }}

```
- name: Copy Playbooks
  copy:
    src: /etc/ansible/playbooks/hands_on_ansible/hands_on_files/mount_nfs.yml
    dest: /home/{{ variable.get('Users') }}/playbooks
```

So what i need to do is add each individual variable to a different home directory using the variables file, which is a loop.

Have googled (obviously) but to no avail. All help is very much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type `Users` is list and it contains 3 items, you can find for information about YAML datastructure in the [related Ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html#yaml-basics).

Basically you will want to iterate over the items in the list and apply your play `Copy Playbooks` for each one. This is a loop and you could do it like :

```
- name: Copy Playbooks
  copy:
    src: /etc/ansible/playbooks/hands_on_ansible/hands_on_files/mount_nfs.yml
    dest: "/home/{{item}}/playbooks"
  loop: "{{ variable.get('Users') }}"
```

A more accurate description of ansible loops can be found [in the documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html).

---

**EDIT :** The above solution is for Ansible >= 2.5. As specified in the documentation :

> Before 2.5 Ansible mainly used the `with_<lookup>` keywords to create loops, the loop keyword is basically analogous to `with_list`.

For Ansible versions < 2.5 the usual way of doing it would be :

```
- name: Copy Playbooks
  copy:
    src: /etc/ansible/playbooks/hands_on_ansible/hands_on_files/mount_nfs.yml
    dest: "/home/{{item}}/playbooks"
  with_items: "{{ variable.get('Users') }}"
```

Comment: Thanks @HugoShaka! great help. worked a treat. Have a good day.